# What is the best way to write a Longs array into a HEX file in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, file, hex

I have an array of Longs (in the range of 10k or maybe 100k long) that I have to place into a HEX file (.wav) as 8-bit little-endians. What is the best way to do this?

I used a simple PUT, but it didn't go as planned. I tried some test values that should yield

**DE A8
CC 16
00 00
1E 5B**

And I got instead

**DE A8 FF FF CC 16 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 5B 00 00**

The code I used is below. Do you have any idea what happenned and how to fix this? In every value I tried, there's always an extra 00 00 or FF FF between records.

```
Sub Gera_sinal()
Dim sinal() As Long

ReDim sinal(3)

'Test values
 sinal(0) = -22306
 sinal(1) = 5836
 sinal(2) = 0
 sinal(3) = 23326

'Creates a file and puts the values in it
Dim n_arq As Integer
Dim path As String

path = "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\App\WAVs\Sinal_VBA.wav"

     Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(path, True)
     a.Close

     n_arq = FreeFile
     Open path For Binary As n_arq

     Put n_arq, , sinal
    Close n_arq

End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The storage size for the data type Long is 4 bytes.  Therefore, since you've declared your array as Long, each value within the array will be stored in the file as 4 bytes.

So, for example, as you know, -22,306 converts to A8 DE in Hex.  However, since the value is going to be stored as 4 bytes, the actual value stored in the file will be FF FF A8 DE, or DE A8 FF FF in little-endian.

Now, if the range of values is going to be between -32,768 and 32,767, inclusive, you can declare your array as Integer instead.  This will mean that each value will be stored in the file as 2 bytes.  So -22,306 will be stored as DE A8.

By the way, you can avoid using the FileSystemObject object in order to truncate an existing file to 0 bytes.  Instead, you can use the Kill method to delete the file, when it already exists, since the Open statement in Binary mode will create it when one doesn't already exist.

Accordingly, your macro can be re-written as follows...

```
Sub Gera_sinal()

    Dim sinal() As Integer

    ReDim sinal(3)

    'Test values
    sinal(0) = -22306
    sinal(1) = 5836
    sinal(2) = 0
    sinal(3) = 23326

    'Creates a file and puts the values in it
    Dim n_arq As Integer
    Dim path As String

    path = "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\App\WAVs\Sinal_VBA.wav"

    'delete file, if it already exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill path
    On Error GoTo 0

    n_arq = FreeFile
    Open path For Binary Access Write As n_arq
        Put n_arq, , sinal
    Close n_arq

End Sub
```